# How can I override a Nix derivative without throwing `cannot coerce a set to a string`?

Tags: nixos

Or, the goal: *How can I take a single package from Nix unstable in a declarative manner?*

I'm new to NixOS and currently trying to install a newer version of Consul than the default `0.5.2` of my NixOS version (latest stable). I'm attempting this by overriding the derivative in my `/etc/nix/configuration.nix`.

I'd like to keep running stable, but I found unstable had the version of Consul that I wanted (`0.7.0`) already, and so I decided to use this package's attributes as a starting point to override https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/servers/consul/default.nix

I copied it for most part into my `configuration.nix`, here are the relevant sections:

```
nixpkgs.config.packageOverrides = pkgs: rec {
  consul = pkgs.lib.overrideDerivation pkgs.consul (attrs: rec {
    version = "0.7.0";
    name = "consul-${version}";
    rev = "v${version}";

    goPackagePath = "github.com/hashicorp/consul";

    src = pkgs.fetchFromGitHub {
      owner = "hashicorp";
      repo = "consul";
      inherit rev;
      sha256 = "04h5y5vixjh9np9lsrk02ypbqwcq855h7l1jlnl1vmfq3sfqjds7";
    };

    # Keep consul.ui for backward compatability
    passthru.ui = pkgs.consul-ui;
  });
};

environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
  vim
  which
  telnet
  consul-ui
  consul-alerts
  consul-template
  consul
];
```

I'm running `nix-build (Nix) 1.11.2` which throws:

```
$ nixos-rebuild switch
building Nix...
building the system configuration...
error: cannot coerce a set to a string, at /etc/nixos/configuration.nix:19:7
(use ‘--show-trace’ to show detailed location information)
```

When I look at line `19` it's where `name` is set to `"consul-${version}"`.

Why there is type-coercion going on here? Any tips will be greatly appreciated!

I'm also wondering if there is a better way to run just a single package in unstable, yet doing so declaratively from `configuration.nix`, rather than imperatively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Nix/NixOS :)

Whenever you need to know more about the error you can use `--show-trace` and that would give you more verbose error. In your case you would see something like

```
error: while evaluating the attribute ‘passthru’ of the derivation ‘consul-0.7.0’ at /home/rok/tmp/consul.nix:6:3:
cannot coerce a set to a string, at /home/rok/tmp/consul.nix:6:3
```

Which should point you that an error actually happens at passthru, line. If you comment it out it will probably build. I'm assuming some recursive calls are at play here and error occurs when it tries to evaluate consul/consul-ui packages.

As for overriding only one package from unstable channel something like this is needed

```
let
  unstable_pkgs = import ./path/to/unstabe/nixpkgs {};
  # or
  # unstable_pkgs = import (pkgs.fetchFromGitHub {...}) {};
in {
  ...
  nixpkgs.config.packageOverrides = pkgs: rec {
    consul = unstable_pkgs.consul;
  };
  ...
}
```

I haven't try the above, but I'm assuming it will work.

Comment: Thanks Rok! I got it to work with your help. The relevant bits of my `configuration.nix` now look like so: https://gist.github.com/kvz/a68e2f2c1e86dded9c484ed3c1a15025, pinning Consul to todays commit, so I won't get unintended upgrades when I start adding Consul machines.

Answer (score 5):

To add to what Rok said:

> Which should point you that an error actually happens at passthru, line. If you comment it out it will probably build. I'm assuming some recursive calls are at play here and error occurs when it tries to evaluate consul/consul-ui packages.

**If you're just starting out, you can safely ignore what follows and perhaps come back to it if/when you're curious about the nitty-gritty.**

The problem here is that `overrideDerivation` is a kind of low-level approach to overriding things. Behind `stdenv.mkDerivation`, we have a much smaller primitive function called `derivation`. The `derivation` function takes some attributes and (more or less -- see the docs for the finer details) just passes those attributes as environment variables during the build. The `stdenv.mkDerivation` function, on the other hand, has a whole bunch of smarts layered on top that massages the attributes given to it before passing them onto `derivation` -- and in some cases, as is the case with `passthru`, it doesn't pass the attribute to `derivation` at all.

Back to `overrideDerivation`: it takes the final, tweaked attributes that `stdenv.mkDerivation` would pass to `derivation`, and just before that happens it allows you to override those attributes with the function you give it (e.g. that implies that, at that point, `passthru` has already been removed). When your function adds a `passthru`, that makes its way into `derivation`, which then wants to coerce the value of `passthru` into a string so it can make `passthru` an environment variable during the build; however, because `passthru` now points at a attribute-set, and such coercion isn't supported, Nix then complains.

So this sort of puts us in an odd situation. To illustrate, I'll copy the source for the consul package here:

```
{ stdenv, lib, buildGoPackage, consul-ui, fetchFromGitHub }:

buildGoPackage rec {
  name = "consul-${version}";
  version = "0.6.4";
  rev = "v${version}";

  goPackagePath = "github.com/hashicorp/consul";

  src = fetchFromGitHub {
    owner = "hashicorp";
    repo = "consul";
    inherit rev;
    sha256 = "0p6m2rl0d30w418n4fzc4vymqs3vzfa468czmy4znkjmxdl5vp5a";
  };

  # Keep consul.ui for backward compatability
  passthru.ui = consul-ui;
}
```

(Note that `buildGoPackage` is a wrapper around `stdenv.mkDerivation`.)

You might be familiar with e.g. `consul.override`, which allows you to supply different inputs (e.g. maybe a different version of `consul-ui`, or `buildGoPackage`), but it doesn't allow you to override things that *aren't* inputs (e.g. `src`, `passthru`, etc). Meanwhile, `overrideDerivation` allows you to modify the attrs given to `derivation`, but *not* the ones given to `stdenv.mkDerivation`. Ideally there would be something in-between, that would allow for manipulating the attrs given to `stdenv.mkDerivation`, and it so happens that there's a PR open to address this:

https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/18660

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation! Wish I could triple-upvote!

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! I think I finally grok what overideDerivation is actually doing.